# Problems generating random classNames for HTML tags in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, random

Hello everyone!

This might be a silly question but I can't figure out why the className variable in the console.log has a different value from the one used in the className attribute of the `<p>`.

I'm trying to generate random class names for HTML tags so then I can create CSSStyleSheets with rules to these HTML tags. Since, in this example, the css prop is the same the styling is working but the className variables in the tag and in console.log are different and that's what I can't understand why.

Am I missing something obvious or is this somehow the intended behaviour?

The code is this:

```js
import React from 'react'

const constructCss = (css) => {
  const style = document.createElement('style')
  document.head.appendChild(style)
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css))
}

const constructCssStyleAndReturnClassName = (css) => {
  const generateRandomString = (length=6) => Math.random().toString(20).substr(2, length)
  const className = `styled-${generateRandomString(8)}`
  constructCss(`.${className} ${css}`)
  return className
}

const Pa = ({css, children}) => {
  const className = constructCssStyleAndReturnClassName(css)
  console.log('Rendering with className: ', className)
  return <p className={className}>{children}</p>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Pa css={`{ background-color: blue; color: white }`}>Helloooooo</Pa>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's also here in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-babbage-x7iev?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I was expecting to get, for example, 'styled-3812a621' both in the console.log and className in the `<p>`. But as @johane pointed out this was happening because the component was rendering twice and the console.log was slow. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code Sandbox seems too slow to catch it with `console.log`, but if you set a debugger (or `console.count`) in your `Pa` component you will see that you get 2 renders, which means you get two different random class names. I would guess that it logs the first, but then uses the second.

Comment: That's exactly what happened! I didn't know about the `console.count` and putting it in the component does show 2 renders. Also didn't know that `console.log` could be a problem in being slow to only log the first value! Thank you so much for poiting out to the right direction :)

Comment: So I was wondering why it was rendering twice and I found that it is something related to React.StrictMode which is wrapping the App.js. If anyone wanna see more about that you can [check here](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I did not know about that behavior of StrictMode.